# Pod install error flutter: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging":

Tags: ios, flutter, kubernetes, cocoapods

I ran into this error while trying to run pod install. Pls what can I do to fix this???

Kindly note that I have tried deleting podfile.lock, flutter clean, pod update, pod repo update, delete ios/pods file and .symlinks folder. None of this fix my issue. Pls help

```
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '9.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '9.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '9.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '9.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_dynamic_links: Using Firebase SDK version '9.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '9.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleAppMeasurement":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GoogleAppMeasurement (= 9.5.0)

  In Podfile:
    google_mobile_ads (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mobile_ads/ios`) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 8.13.0) was resolved to 8.13.0, which depends on
        GoogleAppMeasurement (< 9.0, >= 7.0)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `GoogleAppMeasurement` inside your development pod `google_mobile_ads`.
   You should run `pod update GoogleAppMeasurement` to apply changes you've made.
```

Comment: Have you run "pod install --repo-update" and "pod update GoogleAppMeasurement" as described in the error?

Comment: Yes I have done that. The issue still comes back

Comment: updating google_mobile_ads to the latest version solves it for me.

Comment: Go ahead and answer this question then so it can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that works for me is;

1. I change google_mobile_ads: 1.1.0 from pubspec.yaml to google_mobile_ads: ^2.1.0
2. Run flutter pub get
3. delete podfile.lock and .symlinks folder inside ios folder.
4. Run pod install, flutter clean and then flutter run.
5. It didn't run at first, I tried pod install --repo-update and flutter run again. Boom my build is successful